Logging issue in my application after migrating from Wildfly 18 to 33
I am currently migrating from Wildfly 18 to 33, passing through version 26. I noticed that upon switching to 26, my application logs stopped appearing.
I made the following changes in my pom.xml:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

I added the logback exclusion because I encountered this error:

LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath.
Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory loaded from jar:file:/../wildfly-33.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/slf4j/impl/main/slf4j-jboss-logmanager-2.0.1.Final.jar!/).
If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml:  org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory

Despite this error, the logs appear.
I am using org.jboss.logging.Logger for logging.
How do I solve this problem?
I accessed the console, where I had to reconfigure the standalone settings after the migration by removing 'default-migration' because I couldn't connect anymore. I then removed and re-added the root-logger configuration. When I do this, the server displays my application logs again. However, upon restarting the server, the logs disappear.

You're looking in the wrong place. A test dependency and its dependencies are not something that are included in the artifact you deploy to WildFly, so something else is pulling in Logback as well.

Without knowing which version of Spring Boot you are using (as you are coming from Wildfly 18, propably some 2.x version). Which is probably not compatible with newer Wildfly versions due to library incompatibilities. Not sure if you can switch classloading to application-first (or whatever it is called in wildfly).

I agree with you. After reflection, I think that not excluding logback triggers an error, and therefore does not continue the processes which cause the application not to log. I don't know if it can give a clue, but the application gives logs at the beginning, and then not a single line of log info. It's from these 2 lines:
INFO [io.undertow.servlet]  Initializing AtmosphereFramework
INFO [io.undertow.servlet] 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath. But the error stacks pass fine
I passed vaadin 23 to 24 and spring 2.x to 3.3.2. Wildfly runs in 33.

Try executing to define the org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem system property to none. In CLI you can do /system-property=org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem:add(value=none). If that works I can expand further.

I executed the CLI command and I have the logs! I imagine it's because there are several loggers and he's using the wrong one?
